# Pass parameter to Outlook Script

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run a script on a outlook email message. I want to be able to pass a parameter to the VB script. I was trying to make the script do different things based on which outlook folder the message was moved to. But in the outlook rules the "Run a script" seems to always be the first action that is performed. So when the script runs the message is still in the inbox, and other actions like categories etc haven't yet been assigned from the rule?

Answer (score 0):

*(This is not exactly programming related... I think this belongs on superuser.com. - [Get the beta password here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/))*

You could make two separate rules. One applies the changes, the next runs the script. The rules themselves can be ordered any way you like.

Comment: He's trying to write a program, and he's looking for a workaround to an API limitation - why is it not programming related? It's just as programming-related as questions about CSS, or how to change the letter spacing in the Eclipse code editor. Methinks the problem here is: it's VBA.

Comment: To me the core problem seems to be that one cannot influence the order certain actions are applied within a single Outlook rule. That one of the actions involves VBA code does not make the whole issue programming related.